# Is it possible to prevent a member function from being redefined?

Tags: c++, object, polymorphism

I would like a class B not to be able to redefine one of the member function of its base class A. Is there a way to do that?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers. Can I prevent non-virtual member functions from being overridden as well?

Comment: What do you mean "redefine"? Do you mean shadow/hide, or is it virtual and you mean override?

Comment: And why would you want that? I hate `final` in Java.

Comment: I mean override. The function in both classes would have the exact same signature.

Comment: 'Overriding' is term that explicitly applies to *virtual* functions. Non-virtual functions are *hidden* or *shadowed* by derived class functions, which you can't stop in any way.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your methods are `virtual`, in C++11 you can prevent overriding them with `final`.

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void foo() final;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   void foo(); // <-- error
};
```

You can't prevent hiding.

Comment: `sealed` isn't a C++ keyword. Perhaps you are thinking of C#?

Comment: `final`, not `sealed`, and only in C++11.

Comment: Looks like `sealed` is a Microsoft extension.

Comment: @Rob MSVC supports sealed, I guess that's what threw me off. I checked the standard and it's not there, you're right.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I did mean sealed, but I check the standard and it doesn't exist. Weird, because MSVC supports it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: MSVC has many non-standard extensions. Luckily, it also has an option to disable them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour what option is that?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I can't remember; it's a while since I've used it. I'm pretty sure there's a checkbox somewhere in the project settings labelled "Disable Microsoft extensions" which gives you a closer approximation to standard C++.

Comment: @Luchian: `/Za` IIRC. You can find it in the project properties under 'C/C++' -> 'Language' -> 'Disable Language Extensions'.

Comment: The `/Za` switch breaks VC++'s own standard library; VC++'s own developers recommend to not use it.

Comment: @ildjarn: do you mean it breaks `<windows.h>` ? AFAIK the MSVC Standard Library is derived from Dinkumware's, and that one is very tolerant.

Comment: @MSalters : No, I mean the C++ standard library. Stephan T. Lavavej, MS' standard library maintainer, has posted about this many times on the Boost dev mailing list and elsewhere. The _reason_ it breaks the standard library is that while it correctly disables all MS extensions, it also erroneously breaks some standard-conformant behavior. STL said he's lobbying hard to have the compiler switch removed altogether since no one appears to be willing to put any effort into fixing it and it does more harm than good.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean disallowing a derived class to *override* a virtual function of its base class, C++11 introduced a way to do that with a `final` *virt-specifier* (as it's called in the standard):

```
struct B{
  virtual void f() final;
};

struct D : B{
  void f(); // error: 'B::f' marked 'final'
};
```

I don't know which compilers support that, though. Probably GCC 4.7 and Clang.

Comment: Dunno about Clang, but I can confirm GCC 4.7.

Comment: It also works in VC++ using the keyword `sealed` instead of `final`.

Comment: @ildjarn: That would be a non-standard extension then. Atleast you can get portability with that. `#ifdef _MSC_VER #define VIRT_FINAL sealed #else #define VIRT_FINAL final` or somesuch.

Comment: Pre-standard, not non-standard. ;-] It's been there since VC++ 2005.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I prevent non-virtual member functions from being overridden as
>   well?

No you can't, BUT from another side you can... if you're not shore if will you acctualy override base method or not in your derived class you can check whther you're overriding an method or not using a keywod `override`

when applying that keywod to your method you make shore that you accutaly realy want override that mathod.

so if signature of inherted method is the same as the signature of base method you'll get compile time error, say that derived method does not override base method.

so **using `override` keyword you are telling the compiler that you DO NOT want to everride it**.
by not using override keywod **you never know wether you override it or not**.

consider following example:

```
class A
{
public:
    void f() {std::cout << "A";}
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    void f() override {std::cout << "B";}
};
```

this result in compile time error because you can't override base method.
by not using the override keyword you'll of course be able to override it.

override keywod is introduced in C++0x standard and is supported by visual studio 2010.